# How can I use a table in LUA for pinging multiple devices and detecting change in variable status

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I am trying to ping a number of IP address on a local network at defined intervals and then send a message only when a device connects.  I have managed to get it to work for a single device, but when I add additional devices to the table the code fails.
Many thanks in advance.

An earlier version without the table and just a single IP address works perfectly.  But adding the table and the "for key,value loop" only works if a single entry is in the table.

```
local tble = {
    ["device name"] = "192.168.1.204"
}
for key,value in pairs(tble) do

statuscheckIP=os.execute("arping -f -w 3 " .. value)


if statuscheckIP  ~= lastcheckIP then
if statuscheckIP == 0 and lastcheckIP == 256 then
subject ="" ..key.. " , ( IP Address " ..value.. ") Connected"
message = "Connection Alert\nThe device named " ..key.. ", with the IP address " ..value.. " has just connected to the WiFi network"
  --send email notification
  luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SmtpNotification1", "SendEmail", { Recipient_Name="SomeOne", Recipient_eMail="someone@somewhere.com", Subject= subject, Message=message }, 24)luup.call_action("urn:upnporg:serviceId:SmtpNotification1","ResetCount",{}, 24)
  else
  end
 end
end
lastcheckIP = statuscheckIP
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the code fails"?

Comment: Hi Phins. By fail the code either no longer sends email notifications if devices listed in the table connect, or notifications are sent for one device but confirm a connection even thought the device is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is valid. There are not many reasons why this would fail due to more entries in your table.

> `os.execute` Execute an operating system shell command. This is like the C system() function. The system dependent status code is returned.

Running `os.execute` will start a arping and return an exitcode. Then you are comparing that `statuscheckIP == 0` a `lastcheckIP == 256`. The if before is redundant. If true you are sending your message and continuing.

After worked though all entries you are setting lastcheckIP to statusCheckIP and this is propably your error. It should be before the last if and inside your loop. But even then does not make sense if `0` is the only correct return code. If lastcheckIP is set to any other value your both if's will never go true again.

Either your last line `lastcheckIP = statuscheckIP` is wrongly placed, `lastcheckIP` was never initialized to 256 or you should rethink your whole program.

**EDIT:**

After understanding the intention of the provided program, I've created a probably working example. This should show you, how to easily use tables in Lua as a structures. I was not able to test the following code.

```
local WAIT_TIME = 10

local STATUS_CODE_CONNECTED = 0
local STATUS_CODE_NOT_CONNECT = 256 -- not sure about this (return code from arping for failure)

local device_table = 
{
    ["device_name1"] =
    {
        ip = "<ip address>",
        status_code = STATUS_CODE_NOT_CONNECT
    },
    ["device_name1"] =
    {
        ip = "<ip address>",
        status_code = STATUS_CODE_NOT_CONNECT
    } 
    -- , ...
}

while true do
    -- check for changed return codes
    for device_name, device in pairs(device_table) do
        local temp_status_code = os.execute("arping -f -w 3 " .. device.ip)

        -- status code changed
        if temp_status_code ~= device.status_code then

            -- device connected
            if temp_status_code == STATUS_CODE_CONNECTED then
                local subject = "" .. device_name .. " , ( IP Address " .. device.ip .. ") Connected"
                local message = "Connection Alert\nThe device named " .. device_name .. ", with the IP address " .. device.ip .. " has just connected to the WiFi network"

                --send email notification

                luup.call_action(
                    "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SmtpNotification1", 
                    "SendEmail", 
                    { 
                        Recipient_Name = "SomeOne", 
                        Recipient_eMail = "someone@somewhere.com", 
                        Subject = subject, 
                        Message = message 
                    }, 24)
                luup.call_action(
                    "urn:upnporg:serviceId:SmtpNotification1", 
                    "ResetCount",
                    { }, 24)
            end

            -- update last device status_code if changed
            device.status_code = temp_status_code
        end
    end

    os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(WAIT_TIME)) -- wait some time for next check
end
```

If I've understand you wrongly and you either do not want to have this program run all the time or do not want to have all addresses in a table then you should ask again or somewhere else because that would be out off topic.

Comment: Thank you Phins for taking the time to look at the code.  I need to look harder at the code as you suggest to see where Im going wrong.Just to confirm, the code as currently shown about actually works.  It is only when I add an addition Key and Value to the table that it does not produce the expected results.

Comment: @Ruf1 The last think I could imagine is that your firewall, router or your / their operating system is blocking your arping call

Comment: Hi Phins. I tried your comments in your suggested answer but no luck. I have a feeling your are right and I need to rethink my code. If you have any ideas how I can get this to work I'd be grateful if you could share them.

Comment: Could you try to explain what you want to achive with "lastcheckIP"? (Do you want to check, if an message was already sent do this IP?)

Comment: Hi Phins. I want to ping a table of IP addressea on a local network. I ping a regular intervals. When a device state changes from not connected to connected I want to send an email to notify that a device has connected. So I only send an email when the IP address connection state has changed from not connected to connected. For all other states no email is send.  Lastcheckip was my attempt at creating a variable for comparison to know if the connection status had changed.

Comment: Hi Phins. Thank you for the new code. I will try this as soon as I get back to my computer in a few hours . Thank you so much. Looking forward to trying it.

Comment: Hi Phins.  I have just tested the code.  The scripts runs on a cron so I dont need the timer, so removed that.  Then when I ran the script I got a script fail to run error.  I removed the 'while true do' and the script run error was removed, however when the I re-ran the script it sent the email notification each I time I ran it even when there wasn't a change in connection status. What does the while true do in this script?

Comment: Your problem is that variable values DO NOT persist between restarts of your script. Every time you start your script again, all your variables are reseted to either your defined default value (here ex. all status codes to 256) or to null. To result in a continues working script, your program has to loop (https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html)

Comment: @Ruf1 I think currently your biggest problem is lack of knowledge about Lua (or maybe Programming). I suggest you to first learn Lua and come back later, its not a big language

Comment: Phins. I really appreciate your help and advice. Thank you.